# Bind sobject to html input element

Tags: inputfield

Below is my code. I am trying to bind sobject to input tag but i am not able to do so. Any solutions?

```
<table class="borderCls">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fnns}" var="fnn" indexvar="fnnNumber">
    <tr class="fnn-table-row">
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-media__figure slds-grid">
            <span class="fnn-text-icon-container">
            <div class="">
                <input type="number" class="slds-input slds-text-body_regular fnn-text" value="{!fnn.Name}" required="true" />
            </div> 
            <div class="slds-col slds-size--6-of-12">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!fnn.Result != ''}" >
                <aura:if isTrue="{!fnn.Result == 'Available'}" >
                    <span style="display:inline-flex;" class="">
                        <div class="">
                            <c:svgIcon svgPath="/resource/SLDS/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#approval" class="fnn-availability-icon" category="action" size="xx-small" name="approval" />
                        </div>
                    </span>    
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    <span style="display:inline-flex;">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-5">
                        <c:svgIcon svgPath="/resource/SLDS/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close" class="fnn-availability-icon" category="action" size="xx-small" name="close" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size--4-of-5">
                            <span class="fnn-reason"><p>{!fnn.Reason}</p></span>    
                        </div>
                    </span>

                </aura:set>
                </aura:if>    
            </aura:if>
            </div>    

            </span>
        </div>
    </tr>   
    </aura:iteration>        
</table>
```

Comment: I have faced similar problem. I have used ui:inputText instead of html input.

Comment: @AjayPrakashDubey but i need only numbers not alphabets

Comment: you can use ui:inputNumber

Comment: @AjayPrakashDubey but it doesnt pass the number sarting with 0 i.e if i input 056567 then it passes 56567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing that could exactly match my requirement i.e allow numbers starting with o eg.0569 and pass 0569 as the value to controller. Also only allow numbers and no other characters.

Finally, I had to apply regex and validate in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this,  Value binding with html elements in lightning framework
it will help you
component:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.question.Answers__r}" var="answer" indexVar="index">  
    <label class="slds-radio" for="{!answer.Id}">
        <input type="radio" checked="{!answer.Is_Correct__c}" onchange="{!c.markAnswer}"
               data-id="{!answer.Id}" name="options" id="{!answer.Id}" data-ansIndex="{!index"}/>                  
        <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
        <span class="slds-form-element__label">{!answer.Description__c}</span>
    </label>
</aura:iteration>
```

Controller:

```
({ 
    markAnswer : function(cmp, event, helper) { 
        var question = cmp.get("v.question");
        var answers = question.Answers__r
        var selectedAnsIdx = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-ansIndex');

        for(var i = 0;i < answers.length;i++){
            if(i != selectedAnsIdx){
                answers[i].Is_Correct__c = false;
            }
        }

        answers[selectedAnsIdx].Is_Correct__c = true;
        cmp.set("v.question",question);
    }
});
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

lightning:input gives a number. its in beta but we are using this in prod apps it seems to work fine.
like this.

```
<lightning:input type="number" step="1" value="{!v.numberValue}" />
```

may be it will work fine....

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **ui:inputText** or **lightning:input**, this will fix your issue